# How do I retrieve aggregate measures from R when I need to pass disaggregated data in Tableau?

Tags: r, tableau-api, survival-analysis

I have extensively read and re-read the Troubleshooting R Connections and Tableau and R Integration help documents, but as a new Tableau user they just aren't helping me.

I need to be able to calculate Kaplan-Meier survival probabilities across any dimensions that are dragged onto the sheet. Ideally, I would be able to retrieve this in a tabular format at multiple time points, but for now, I would be happy just to get it at a single time point.

My data in Tableau have columns for [event-boolean] and [time to event]. Let's say I also have columns for Gender and District.

Currently, I have a calculated field [surv] as:

```
SCRIPT_REAL('
library(survival);
fit <- summary(survfit(Surv(.arg2,.arg1) ~ 1), times=365);
fit$surv'
,  min([event-boolean])
,  min([time to event])
)
```

I have messed with Computed Using, Addressing, Partitions, Aggregate Measures, and parameters to the R function, but no combination I have tried has worked.

If [District] is in Columns, do I need to change my SCRIPT_REAL call or do I just need to change some other combination of levers?

Comment: I used [Andrew's solution](http://community.tableau.com/message/245531#245531) to solve this problem. Essentially,

Answer (score 0):

I used [Andrew's solution](http://community.tableau.com/message/245531#245531) to solve this problem. Essentially,
- Turn off Aggregate Measures
- In the Measure Values shelf, select Compute Using > Cell
- In the calculated field, start with `If FIRST() == 0 script_*() END`
- Ctrl+drag the measure to the Filters shelf and use a Special > Non-null filter.